# Is there a more proper place than /etc/rc.local for writing to configure binfmt?

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, binfmt

I want to be able to run clr (>NET/mono) exes on my redhat machines, so I add the following to /etc/rc.local:

```
echo ':CLR:M::MZ::/opt/mono-head/bin/mono:' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

This works fine, but is there a more appropriate config file specifically intended for configuring binfmt as opposed to the kitchen sink rc.local?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an appropriate use of `/etc/rc.local` to me.  The running of this is a system wide need, so that takes a single user environment off the table, and it isn't a service that warrants the creation of something under `/etc/init.d` or some such similar place where services are kept.

Comment: Its appropiate if theres nothing specialized. I would think that a slightly over-engineered solution where there was a separate rc script would make it easier to automatically configure binfmt associations via RPMs etc.

Comment: @JustinDearing - this is a bit of a gray area, I would go with the `rc.local` option, mainly because over the course of my career, I've seen things similar to this done in that same way. So if anything, it's consistent to rationalize it this way, as to how others would do it.

Comment: agreed. as just a sysadmin this is the right answer. If I made a distro and sat on the LSB committiee I'd argue for overengineering.

Comment: @JustinDearing - yes it's often safer to do things as others would expect them sometimes rather than what might seem right to just you. Hence why this site is great, lots of others to bounce *your* ideas off of before doing them 8-).

Comment: Debian and derivatives do set up binfmt through a script in `/etc/init.d`, but that's generic support for all installed handlers. Bringing that (pseudo-)service up re-reads the handler descriptions from `/var/lib/binfmts`. Stopping the service deregisters all binfmt handlers from the kernel. However, for a local one-off thing, `/etc/rc.local` is perfectly appropriate.